# Create XPathDocument from XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm using a webservice which returns an `XmlElement` object to my C# program. I would like to read information from the `XmlElement` using Xpath. What is the best way to create an `XPathDocument` from the `XmlElement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [create a navigator directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.createnavigator.aspx) against the XmlElement and use your xpath from there with the navigators Select* methods, no XPathDocument required.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an `XmlElement`, can you not just use `SelectNodes()` / `SelectSingleNode()`?

Also, all `XmlNode`s are `IXPathNavigable`, allowing you to get a navigator.

Finally, you can use `new XmlNodeReader(element)`, and use this to create an `XPathDocument` using the overload that accepts an `XmlReader`.